# Unexpected output during tensor normalization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanted to normalize each row of a matrix.

```
import tensorflow as tf
t = 2
dimension = 300
tf.reset_default_graph()
batch_size = 2 
epsilon = 1e-8
train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
out_embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([t, dimension], tf.float32))
embed_out = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(out_embeddings, train_labels)
out_square = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embed_out), 1, keepdims=True) + epsilon
out_norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embed_out), 1, keepdims=True) + epsilon)
normalized_embed_out = embed_out / out_norm

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    batch_labels = [0, 1]
    square, norm, normalized_embed = session.run([out_square, out_norm, normalized_embed_out],
                                             feed_dict={train_labels: batch_labels})
    print("square:", square)
    print("norm:", norm)
```

But surprisingly I got this result:

```
square: [[1.e-08] [1.e-08]]
norm: [[10000.] [10000.]]
```

Could you please help me to understand the reason?

Comment: Your code can be simplified to `a = tf.Variable(0.0, dtype=tf.float32))`, `a_sqrt = tf.sqrt(a + epsilon)`, `a_scaled = a / a_sqrt`, and the problem still exists. Printing `a_sqrt` will get the value of `1/sqrt(epsilon)` for any `epsilon`.  Interestingly, change the code to `a = tf.constant(0.0)`, or `a_sqrt = tf.sqrt(a + epsilon) + 0.0`, or simply leaving out the division results in a correct answer. I do not know what happens here. The graph in tensorboard also does not provide many insights.